# Is 1/(n+2) bounded or unbounded?

Tags: real-analysis

I need to show that $K = \left(\frac{1}{n+2}\right)$ for $n=1,2,3...$ is either bounded or unbounded. I am firm on that it is bounded because the function starts of at $1/3$ and decreases from there. Shouldn't $1/3$ be a upper bound? My proofs class partner is telling me it's unbounded. However, it has a upper bound...no?

Comment: Are you talking about taking a limit $n$ going to infinity?

Comment: Note that $1/3$ is an *upper bound*.

Comment: @AndréNicolas. Sorry, good point. I was thinking lower from the index perspective, but it's definitely an upper bound from a magnitude perspective.

Answer (score 1):

We see that when n = 1, 2, 3... 1/(n+2) is 1/3, 1/4, 1/5... However this sequence is decreasing and always greater than 0. In fact, it's bounded below by 0 and bounded above by its largest value 1/3.